# php parent class edited variable

Tags: php, class, oop

I have coding new project. I have create a new system because its so mixed. Firstly i have main class and its have 3 variables;

- database variable: its have ezSQL class and name is $db
- stored classes: i have helper classes and its stored this variable its named with $store
- stored data: i have put site options and other mysql datas its name $stored_data

and its in code:

```
class main {
  var $db;
  var $store;
  var $stored_data;

  public function main(){
    global $db; // ezsql class
    $this->db=$db;
  }

  public function get_helper_class($classname){
    if(isset($this->store[$classname]))
      return $this->store[$classname];
    include_once "helperclass/".$classname.".php";
    $this->store[$classname]=new $classname;
    return $this->store[$classname];
  }
}
```

and example helper class its name option

```
class option extends main {
  public function get_option($optname){
    if($this->stored_data['option'][$optname])
      return $this->stored_data['option'][$optname];
    // else get result and put stored_data
  }
}
```

and if i use second helper

```
class example extends main{
  public function get_data($dataname){
    return $this->get_helper_class('option')->get_option('optionname');
  }
}
```

but when i call helper class my helper cant see $store['option'] data its create new option class.
problem:

> the helper class cant get $store, $db, $stored_data variables from main class.

I want get edited data and variables but its allways create new datas.
what can i do?

Comment: Please show a test case that shows the problem.

Comment: There are no `$store`, `$db`, `$stored_data` variables in your main *class*. Those variables belong to *objects* (i.e. *instances* of the class). Each object has its own set of values for these variables.

Comment: Your class depends on global state, includes external scripts and is leaking encapsulation .. what did you expect? Add `eval` or `goto` and you will be a prime candidate for "worst code of the week" award.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get the correct option?  It also depends on how you are setting the options:

```
return $this->get_helper_class('option')->get_option($dataname);
```